# self signed certificate for implementing https

Tags: iis, ssl, https

I have a server with public IP and hold a website on it. I don't have a domain and my web server is IIS, then I created a self signed certificate in the server and bind it to my website.  When I want to access to my website using  a link like **http**://*.*.*.*/test. I can access to the website with **https** in localhost in the server. but I can't access to the website from a client browser with **https**and I get this error in client browser:ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out to solve it. Port 443 was closed in the server.

Comment: Accept this answer and close the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Your server most likely doesn't support TLS (v1.0 or higher) but only SSLv3. That's a common cause for this error. SSLv3 is blocked in most browsers because of [the POODLE vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) ([CVE-2014-3566](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-3566)). You should review your server settings and upgrade them accordingly.

You can test your website at the awesome [SSL Test from SSL Labs](https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/). This will point out errors like these and it helps you create a secure config. Please keep in mind that any score below A is in urgent need of improvement.